# How can I instantiate an injected class (using Spring) before logback configuration

Tags: spring, configuration, logback, applicationcontext

I am using spring to inject a class into my PropertyDefiner implementation which will be used to help set up some properties within the logback.xml file (through [dynamic property loading](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingPropsOnTheFly)).

I'd love to get this class loaded and instantiated before logback is configured. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution resulted in not implementing a PropertyDefiner. The original question became an issue of not having the application context from spring to set the dynamic properties. I'm not sure why, but code in a later listener (after the Spring listeners) would get called (invoking the LoggerFactory call) before the application context was available. I tried a number of things, until I starting looking at a different approach.

Instead of using dynamic properties I created a listener (called on server startup) which then programmatically sets up my appender with the properties I want (through the createAdminNotifyAppender).

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0)
{
    //Set up the property reader to pull the correct properties
    ServletContext context = arg0.getServletContext();
    ApplicationContext appContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(context);
    propReader = (AppConfigPropertiesReader)appContext.getBean("propertySourcesPlaceholder");

    LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    createAdminNotifyAppender(lc, propReader);
}
```

The createAdminNotify method simply sets up an appender and adds it to the logging context. (if you're really interested, you can see that method's implementation on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527702/logback-programatically-added-smtpappender-leaves-message-body-blank)).

Now I have a separate and modular listener that I can add to other apps that are using logback, but possibly with different properties. The properties are pulled from a database and can also vary by environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using annotations in Spring, it's convenient to do this by marking the class (i.e. the dependency) you'll be injecting as @Component and then using @Autowired in your PropertyDefiner implementation. This ensures that the first class will be instantiated first. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch04s12.html

Any other initialization you require could be achieved using instance initializer blocks http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: Using the \@component and \@Autowired annotations did not work for me. Neither did implementing ApplicationContextAware to get the application context. It appears that the application context is not initialized yet at the time I need to make this call.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this can be done elegantly at present time (2012-07). However, support for injection has been requested in [LOGBACK-719](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-719).

If your bean factory implements  AutowireCapableBeanFactory, given the Spring Applicaton context, you could invoke [autowireBean(Object existingBean)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#autowireBean%28java.lang.Object%29) to autowire the bean. Here is a tentative implementation:

```
class Your.PropertyDefiner implements PropertyDefiner, LifeCycle {   
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("myKey")
  String myKey; 

  public void start() {
    ApplicationContext appContext = ... somehow get the spring app context
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    factory.autowireBean(this); // declare victory
  }
}
```

The `start()` method will be invoked only if your PropertyDefiner implements the [LifeCycle](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/spi/LifeCycle.html) interface. Moreover, you need logback version 1.0.7 or later. Earlier versions do not invoke `start()`.

Comment: It seems the issue here is that line "somehow get the spring app context". That's the road block that sent me to the alternative solution I've posted.