# Logback - Programatically added SMTPAppender leaves message body blank

Tags: logback

What am I missing? I have the below code which successfully sends an email, but the body of the email is empty. I'd think it has to do with the patternLayout, but everything looks okay. Any ideas on what is going on?

```java
private void createAdminNotifyAppender(LoggerContext lc, AppConfigPropertiesReader propReader)
{
    logger.info("Setting up logback admin_notify logging");

    //Set up the admin notify appender programatically (needs to use the properties from the propReader above)
    OnMarkerEvaluator markerEvaluator = new OnMarkerEvaluator();
    markerEvaluator.addMarker(LogbackMarker.ADMIN_NOTIFY.toString());
    String adminEmails = propReader.getProperty("adminEmail");
    PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
    patternLayout.setPattern("[\\(%-6threadHash\\) app=iv  %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5level %-25logger{25} - %msg%n");

    SMTPAppender adminNotifyAppender = new SMTPAppender();
    adminNotifyAppender.setContext(lc);
    adminNotifyAppender.setEvaluator(markerEvaluator);
    adminNotifyAppender.setSMTPHost(propReader.getProperty("smtpHost"));
    for (String adminEmail : adminEmails.split(",")) { adminNotifyAppender.addTo(adminEmail); };
    adminNotifyAppender.setFrom(propReader.getProperty("sysEmailAddressNoReply"));
    adminNotifyAppender.setSubject("System Alert! [" + propReader.getProperty("environment") + "]");
    adminNotifyAppender.setLayout(patternLayout);
    adminNotifyAppender.start();

    Logger rootLogger = lc.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    rootLogger.addAppender(adminNotifyAppender);
}
```

Comment: FYI, in case you looked at this post before my edit, my first problem of not sending an email at all was due to the all too familiar ol' wrong-property-key bug for the smtpHost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that both the PatternLayout and the OnMarkerEvaluator have the start methods that should be called (MarkerEvaluator seemed to work without it).

Additionally, both need to know the loggerContext as well (set by calling patternLayout.setContext(lc)), otherwise you'll get out put like the following:

```
[(%PARSER_ERROR[threadHash]) app=iv  %PARSER_ERROR[d]] %PARSER_ERROR[level] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] - %PARSER_ERROR[msg]%PARSER_ERROR[n]
```

All is well now.